# Azure Container Instance doesn't show logs

Tags: azure

I have an Azure Container Instance (ACI) that is deployed from a custom container image, which I stored in Azure Container Registry (ACR).

The container image runs a simple Python script (background worker, no exposed ports), which works locally on my Windows 11 system, using Docker Desktop. The script prints some logging text using the `print()` function, so I can see what's going on inside the application.

While ACI starts the container, it doesn't show any events, under the container **Events** tab, and it also doesn't show any logs, under the **Logs** tab.

[image]

However, the container **is** actually running, and I can use the **Connect** tab to open an interactive shell into the container. I can run `ps -aux` and see that the Python script (entrypoint) is actually running.

[image]

**Question**: Why are the Events and Logs not populating in the Azure Container Instances service, even though the container is successfully up and running?

**NOTE**: I am deploying to the West Central US Azure region.

Answer (score 1):

> under the container **Events** tab, and it also doesn't show any logs, under the **Logs** tab.

We have another option in Azure CLI to get the Logs of `Azure Container Instance`.

In Azure Portal, Open `Cloud shell`.

[image]

Run the below command in `Azure Cloudshell - Bash`.

```cs
az container logs --name YourContanerInstanceName --resource-group YourRGName
```

***OutPut of Logs:***

[image]

[image]

To get the Events, use the below CLI Command.

```cs
az container show --resource-group YourRGName --name YourContanerInstanceName
```

***Output of Events:***

[image]

[image]

> Why are the Events and Logs not populating in the Azure Container Instances service, even though the container is successfully up and running?

Also refer [Options to View Container Logs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/).

Reference taken from MSDoc [Container logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-logs) and [Diagnostic Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-get-logs#get-diagnostic-events).